# How to strike text?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

Sorry but I couldn't find this info. How do I strike the text?

Comment: The answer to the linked question answer your question. This is exactly why we keep duplicates around here. Someone searching with the terms you used will find the information now that it is linked. (Ideally it would have been closed before someone answered, thus avoiding duplicating the actual information.)

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate of the one that is linked. The one that is linked asks if markdown has a way to express strikeout, which is doesn't. It does NOT ask how to strike out text, or provide a clear answer on the way to do that.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can strikethrough with the HTML tag `<s>` and the close tag `</s>`.

<s>Like so</s>

```
<s>Like so</s>
```

In chat this effect can be achieved with `---`

```
---Like so---
```

Don't use it too often, though; it doesn't look very good.

Comment: But how to use it in comments ?

Comment: @Tarik I'm fairly certain there's not a way to strike text in comments currently.

Comment: @Emrakul but why if we use some tools like this one: http://adamvarga.com/strike/, we can do it like this T̶e̶x̶t̶, normally there should be a way to do it without using that tool

Comment: @Tarik Please do not use that technique. Exploiting unicode characters creates a problem for people who use [screen-readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader).

Answer (score 22):

You can also use `<strike>striking text</strike>`. It's more typing but it works!

<strike>striking text</strike>

Comment: This is now deprecated as of HTML5