# How do you use strikethrough on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, markdown

I am trying to use strikethrough on [one of my other Stack Exchange questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/321389/163934). (Now updated with working strikethrough) I have tried the following:

- ~~Double tildes~~
- ~Single tildes~
- [strike]Strike[/strike]
- [del]Del[/del]
- [s]S[/s]

None of these work. I know there is a way because I've seen it before on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note that SE uses markdown and HTML, not BBcode. This means that you should use `<>` angle brackets not `[]` square brackets when there is no appropriate Markdown formatting.

Comment: Was going to put that in below answer.

Comment: Please add a [tag:markdown] tag to the question :)

Comment: @Dawny33 I have added it.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180256/how-to-strike-text

Comment: Though there is [very little use for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011) (there is a full revision history to contain such information).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<s>Like this</s>

```
<s> Some random text </s>

<del> Some random text </del>

<strike> Some random text </strike>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in comments

Comment: @Peanut No, they [don't work in the comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31228/302377).

Comment: Thanks for the help, too. Turns out I was using `[]` instead of `<>`.

Comment: @JohnMiliter That's Unicode, not HTML.